# How to use the argument that I passed from another screen using compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to use `accessToken` in the `AccountListScreen` which I pass from `AuthenticationScreen`

Here is code of my MainActivity:

```
composable(
    route = Screen.AuthenticationScreen.route
) {
    AuthenticationScreen(navController)
}
composable(
    route = Screen.AccountListScreen.route + "/{accessToken}"
) {
    AccountListScreen(navController)
}
```

So I'm trying to pass a parameter from my `AuthenticationScreen`:

```
@Composable
fun AuthenticationScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: AuthenticationViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val authorizeUrl: String by viewModel.authorizeUrl.observeAsState("")
    WebPageScreen(urlToRender = authorizeUrl, viewModel = viewModel)
    
    val state = viewModel.state.value
    if (state.accessToken.isNotEmpty()) {
        navController.navigate(Screen.AccountListScreen.route + "/${state.accessToken}")
    }
}
```

And I don't understand how I can now get my parameter in `AccountListScreen`:

```
@Composable
fun AccountListScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: AccountListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
```

**UPDATE**

I try to use the @Alpha 1 solution and get the following error
maybe I'm doing something wrong

But I have a dependency connected:

> implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha10"

**UPDATE 2**
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check out [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a [NavHost](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#create-navhost), a way could be defining the composable like this in your MainActivity

```kotlin
object composablesData {
    const val ACCESS_TOKEN = "ACCESS_TOKEN"
}

...

composable(
    route = Screen.AccountListScreen.route + "/{$ACCESS_TOKEN}"
) {
    val arguments = requireNotNull(it.arguments)
    val token = arguments.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN) //set the correct type
    AccountListScreen(navController,token)
}
```

And the just receive the parameter in your composable

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AccountListScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    token: String,
    viewModel: AccountListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
```

Check [Navigate with arguments](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args) for more details and examples

Comment: I don't know why, but I get an empty string
although at the time of transmission I see that my `accessToken` is not empty

Comment: Can u check please screens in my question in section `UPDATE 2`

Comment: I edited the answer, try using a `const`. And set the route like this `route = Screen.AccountListScreen.route + "/{$ACCESS_TOKEN}"` and the get like this `val token = arguments.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN) `

Comment: But how i need to modify my method in `AuthenticationScreen` if i use `ACCESS_TOKEN` from `composableData`?
`navController.navigate(Screen.AccountListScreen.route + "/${state.accessToken}")`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the argument for a destination by passing a list of navArgument to your screen. refer the code below:

```
composable(
    route = Screen.AccountListScreen.route + "/{accessToken}",
    arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("accessToken") {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                }
            )
) { entry ->
    //reading the access token
    val accessToken = entry.arguments?.getString("accessToken") ?: ""
    AccountListScreen(navController)
}
```

Comment: Can u check please my Update?